# windows-xp startup program startup folder started

Tags: windows-xp, startup

In windows-xp there are a lot of points where programs can be started automatically.

I would like to start a program before the programs in the startup folder are started. The user is logged on automatically, so there's not a big delay between starting up windows and logging in.

It must be a solution where i'm sure that the programs in the Startup folder are not started. So maybee the program should start before explorer.exe is started.

I see i can add the program in the registry (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) or create a service, but i'm not sure or thats the correct point.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: I'm no Windows programmer but I'm fairly sure `Run` is the correct point - it's where most apps put themselves

Comment: Yes, `Run` is what you're looking for. But there's no guarantee that your program will be started in any particular order. You can't ensure that it will always be started before the other programs in the `Run` key in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Glary Quick Startup](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/quick-startup/). It let's you delay the startup of programs and place them in the order that you want them to load.

I wouldn't use it to disable the startup of items though, see:
[Dealing with Startup Processes](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=149804)

A good app for disabling programs from starting is:
[Startup Control Panel](http://www.mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml)

It doesn't hijack MSconfig registry keys. It's compatible with Win Vista and below.